# Show that $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{a(R+i y)}}{1+e^{R+i y}} d y$ converges to zero as $R \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I want to show that the following integral converges to 0 as $R\rightarrow\infty$:
$$I=
i\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{a(R+i y)}}{1+e^{R+i y}} d y
$$
where $0<a<1$. This should be a simple problem, but somehow I cannot figure out a clever way to show it.

---

I thought an approach would be to show $|I|\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$.
$$|I|\leq\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{a R}}{|1+e^{R+iy}|} d y$$
But where do I go from here? If this is even a good approach. I don't think there is an obvious value that I could choose for the denominator, so the integral is majorized.

Comment: $I\leq 2\pi\Big|\frac{e^{a(R+i y)}}{1+e^{R+i y}} \Big|\leq 2\pi\frac{e^{aR}}{e^R-1}\leq 2\pi e^{R(a-1)}\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow\infty}0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the triangle inequality $|1+e^{R+iy}|\geq ||1|-|e^{R+iy}||=e^R-1$

Also, $\frac{1}{e^R-1}\leq \frac{2}{e^R}$ for $R>\log(2)$. Putting things together we get
$$
I\leq \int^{2\pi}_0\Big|\frac{e^{a(R+iy)}}{1+e^{R+iy}}\Big|\,dy\leq\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{e^{aR}}{e^{R}-1}\,dy\leq4\pi e^{R(a-1)}\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow\infty}0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @OliverDiaz's point: since $|1+e^{R+iy}|^2=1+2e^R\cos y+e^{2R}\ge(e^R-1)^2$,$$|I|\le\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-(1-a)R}}{1-e^{-R}}dy\le\frac{1}{1-e^{-R_0}}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-(1-a)R}dy$$for $R\ge R_0$, with $R_0$ your favourite large positive real.